# Cannot copy files from S3 to EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance which has all inbound traffic open. It is assigned the below role:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:ListObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to copy a file from an S3 bucket to this instance.

```
aws s3 cp s3://test-bucket/test.csv /home/ubuntu/
```

I am getting this error:

> fatal error: Connect timeout on endpoint URL: "https://test-bucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/test.csv"

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the public IP address used by my S3 bucket? I can try to specify that in my outbound rules for the EC2.

Comment: You'll need s3:GetObject on the bucket "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket" in addition to the objects in the bucket "arn:aws:s3:::test-bucket/*"

Comment: @MarkAWard - I tried that. Still same error.

Comment: is the region correct? is your bucket in eu-central-1? can set the region at the cli with `--region=eu-west-1` or in your `~/.aws/config`

Comment: @MarkAWard - I added the region as well. I still get the same error. Do you think I should change my outbound rule? What is the public ip of S3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I get the public IP address used by my S3 bucket? I can try to specify that in my outbound rules for the EC2

Go to your S3 console with a modern, non-mobile web browser.  Click on an object inside of a bucket.  To the right will popout a details pane for the object [that show Overview, Properties and Permissions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/download-objects.html).  In the Overview is the object URL.  Typically it follows this URL pattern:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/<bucket-name>/<object key>`

ping s3.amazonaws.com to get the ip address.  Right now, I get:  52.216.185.149

To get the [range of s3 ips](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) use the [aws powershell command](https://aws.amazon.com/powershell/):

`Get-AWSPublicIpAddressRange -ServiceKey s3 -Region eu-central-1`

```
IpPrefix            IpAddressFormat Region       Service
--------            --------------- ------       -------
52.219.72.0/22      Ipv4            eu-central-1 S3
52.219.44.0/22      Ipv4            eu-central-1 S3
52.92.68.0/22       Ipv4            eu-central-1 S3
54.231.192.0/20     Ipv4            eu-central-1 S3
```

---

A simpler approach to download s3 files to your ubuntu instance, I suggest you follow the [steps in this guide](https://optimalbi.com/blog/2016/07/12/aws-tips-and-tricks-moving-files-from-s3-to-ec2-instance/) that uses the s3 sync command.  The guide uses a role to include your s3 bucket paticulars.  Note the tips indicate that you cannot change IAM roles for your ec2 instance after it has been launched, [but that is not true anymore](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easily-replace-or-attach-an-iam-role-to-an-existing-ec2-instance-by-using-the-ec2-console/).  You can create a role and attach it to an already running instance.  I would use the `s3 cp` command as opposed to `s3 sync`.

Comment: Hi , I added HTTPS outbound to my ec2 as 0.0.0.0/0 and I could transfer the file. When I ping s3.amazon.co the IP address keeps changing. I want to add only those IP address ranges that can be delegated to s3 buckets and objects. How can I do that? From what I understood the s3 in eu-central-1 always returns 52.*.*.* . How can I add this range to my outbound?

Comment: see updated answer - note these ips can change over time, so it might be best to use a role with your bucket name that is suggested in the bottom of the answer.